# tools similar to Valgrind for memory corruption debugging for win32 desktop application

Tags: c++, windows, valgrind, desktop-application, heap-corruption

is there any tools that we can use for windows platform similar to valgrind as used for linux for detect actual heap corruption like invalid read/write for win32 desktop applications. I need to find memory corruption in c++ win32 desktop code.

Comment: For memory corruption specifically [AddressSanitizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/sanitizers/asan?view=msvc-170).

Comment: address sanitizer, undefined behaviour sanitizer, thread sanitizer, memory sanitizer, clang-tidy.